# Writing Spark UDAFs in Scala to return Array type as output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe as below -

```
val myDF = Seq(
(1,"A",100),
(1,"E",300),
(1,"B",200),
(2,"A",200),
(2,"C",300),
(2,"D",100)
).toDF("id","channel","time")

myDF.show()

+---+-------+----+
| id|channel|time|
+---+-------+----+
|  1|      A| 100|
|  1|      E| 300|
|  1|      B| 200|
|  2|      A| 200|
|  2|      C| 300|
|  2|      D| 100|
+---+-------+----+
```

For each `id`, I want the channel sorted by `time` in ascending fashion. I want to implement an UDAF for this logic.

I would like to call this UDAF as -

```
scala > spark.sql("""select customerid , myUDAF(customerid,channel,time) group by customerid """).show()
```

Ouptut dataframe should look like -

```
+---+-------+
| id|channel|
+---+-------+
|  1|[A,B,E]|
|  2|[D,A,C]|
+---+-------+
```

I am trying to write an UDAF but unable to implement it -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._



class myUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

    // This is the input fields for your aggregate function 
    override def inputSchema : org.apache.spark.sql.types.Structype = 
        Structype(
            StructField("id" , IntegerType)
            StructField("channel", StringType)
            StructField("time", IntegerType) :: Nil
        )

    // This is the internal fields we would keep for computing the aggregate 
    // output 
    override def bufferSchema : Structype = 
        Structype(
            StructField("Sequence", ArrayType(StringType)) :: Nil
        )

    // This is the output type of my aggregate function 
    override def dataType : DataType = ArrayType(StringType)

    // no comments here
    override def deterministic : Booelan = true 

    // initialize 
    override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) : Unit = {
        buffer(0) = Seq("")
    }





}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it (no need to define your own UDF):

```
df.groupBy("id")
  .agg(sort_array(collect_list(  // NOTE: sort based on the first element of the struct
         struct("time", "channel"))).as("stuff"))
  .select("id", "stuff.channel")
  .show(false)

+---+---------+
|id |channel  |
+---+---------+
|1  |[A, B, E]|
|2  |[D, A, C]|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, can i write it in `spark.sql(""" """).show` fashion?

Comment: I'm sure you could (although I'm not familiar with the syntax). However, I would recommend using the DataFrame format (rather than SQL style) to have increased type safety (and IDE assistance)

Answer (score 2):

I would not write an UDAF for that. In my experience UDAF are rather slow, especially with complex types. I would use the collect_list & UDF approach:

```
val sortByTime = udf((rws:Seq[Row]) => rws.sortBy(_.getInt(0)).map(_.getString(1)))

myDF
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"time",$"channel")).as("channel"))
  .withColumn("channel", sortByTime($"channel"))
  .show()

+---+---------+
| id|  channel|
+---+---------+
|  1|[A, B, E]|
|  2|[D, A, C]|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions - 1. can you explain the `sortByTime` UDF logic ? , 2. how does `collect_list` work with 2 params?

Answer (score -2):

A much simpler way without UDF.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
myDF.orderBy($"time".asc).groupBy($"id").agg(collect_list($"channel") as "channel").show()
```

Comment: If some one down vote , please let us know what is wrong ? At least we will try to correct